# Integrate a Custom Post Type with Learndash Plugin

Tags: php, custom-post-types, plugin-development

I've registered a custom post type already in wordpress. I am looking for a solution to display that custom post type in learndash course Hierarchy.

Comment: You'll have to ask Learndash's support team about this. Third party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.